# 'unknownProvider' error only on one of two services from same module

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, karma-runner

I have a unit test

```
beforeEach(function(){
 module('app.dependency');
 module('app.module')
})

beforeEach(inject(function($injector){
   var service = $injector.get('someService'); // error here
}))

describe('foo', inject(function(...){
// some test code
}));
```

I get an error on the `$injector.get`, but **only for some services in the same module**. I have `fooService` and `barService`, and I will get an `Unknown provider fooServiceProvider <- fooService` error for `fooService` but not for `barService`.

Both services are part of the same `app.dependency` module, and both files where the services are defined are loaded into karma (which I check by running with `--log-level debug`). They are also loaded after the file where `app.dependency` is defined. That module has no dependency.

Do you have any idea what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have initialized your module more than once. 
I did it by mistake and faced the same error. Had a hard time resolving it.